# SwiftUI Navigation Link Dismisses After Selecting Image from Photo Picker

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm displaying a user profile screen where the user can edit their profile. I give them the option to click the edit button and be able to upload a new profile picture. If they click the edit button I use Photopicker as a popover to let the user select an image once the image is selected I'm able to load it but the view that presented the photo picker is automatically dismissed. I have what I call a maintabview that displays options at the bottom of the screen for the user to navigate the app built like this:

```
struct MainTabView: View {
@State private var selectedIndex = 0

init() {
    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGray6
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        TabView(selection: $selectedIndex) {
            ConversationsView()
                .onTapGesture {
                    selectedIndex = 0
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "bubble.left")
                }
                .tag(0)
            
            ChannelsView()
                .onTapGesture {
                    selectedIndex = 1
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "bubble.left.and.bubble.right")
                }
                .tag(1)
            
            SettingsView()
                .onTapGesture {
                    selectedIndex = 2
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                }
                .tag(2)
        }
        .navigationTitle(tabTitle)
    }
}

var tabTitle: String {
    switch selectedIndex {
    case 0: return "Chats"
    case 1: return "Channels"
    case 2: return "Settings"
    default: return ""
    }
}
```

}

if the user selects the settings view they are presented with some options and the settings view is built like this:

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.systemGroupedBackground)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack(spacing: 32) {
                NavigationLink() {
                    EditProfileView()
                        .interactiveDismissDisabled()
                } label: {
                    SettingsHeaderView()
                }
                
                VStack {
                    ForEach(SettingsCellViewModel.allCases, id: \.self) { viewModel in
                        SettingsCell(viewModel: viewModel)
                    }.padding(.top, -7)
                }
                
                Button {
                    print("Logging out...")
                } label: {
                    Text("Log Out")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .semibold))
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.white)
                }

                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see i have a navigation link that takes the user to the editprofileview once im here everything still works fine but until the user clicks edit and then chooses an image the flow of events is photopicker displayed, user selects image, photopicker dismisses, image loads, editprofileview dismisses for unknown reason. editprofileview is built like this:

```
struct EditProfileView: View {

@State private var fullname = "Eddie Brock"
@State private var showImagePicker = false
@State private var selectedImage: UIImage?
@State private var profileImage: Image?
@State private var selectedItems: [PhotosPickerItem] = []
@State private var data: Data?

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color(.systemGroupedBackground)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 44) {
            //header
            
            VStack {
                // Photo / edit / text
                HStack {
                    // phot / edit
                    VStack {
                        if let data = data, let uiimage = UIImage(data: data) {
                            Image(uiImage: uiimage)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                        } else {
                            Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                        }
                        
                        PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedItems, maxSelectionCount: 1, matching: .images) {
                            Text("Edit")
                        }
                        .onChange(of: selectedItems) { newValue in
                            guard let item = selectedItems.first else { return }
                            item.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) { result in
                                switch result {
                                case .success(let data):
                                    if let data = data {
                                        self.data = data
                                    } else {
                                        print("Data is nil")
                                    }
                                case .failure(let failure):
                                    fatalError(failure.localizedDescription)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    }
                    .padding(.top)
                    
                    Text("Enter your name or change your profile photo")
                        .font(.system(size: 16))
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .padding([.bottom, .horizontal])
                }
                
                Divider()
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                TextField("", text: $fullname)
                    .padding(8)
            }
            .background(Color.white)
            
            
            //status
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                // status text
                Text("Status")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                // status
                NavigationLink {
                    StatusSelectorView()
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Text("At the movies")
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.white)
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.top, 1)
    }
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    .navigationTitle("Edit Profile")
}

func loadImage() {
    guard let selectedImage = selectedImage else { return }
    profileImage = Image(uiImage: selectedImage)
}
```

}

I've tried various solutions such as disabledissmiss, detaillink(false), and also tried bridging with uikit to present viewcontroller to select images ( code below ) but I'm not really sure where to go from here and I'm pretty new to SwiftUI so help would be greatly appreciated.

```
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        return picker
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate ,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        let parent: ImagePicker
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
            self.parent.image = image
            self.parent.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the scenario above by using a NavigationStack as my root view rather than a NavigationView